# Qt Opengl configuration for Windows CE

Tags: qt, opengl-es, windows-ce

I am trying to configure Qt using the OpenGL parameter for a custom WinCE SDK, but I get a compiler error. I found a similar error faced in the http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/37052-WinCE-OpenGL-ES-build-error?s=7aa5ac49753e1c3f1e0b624bb9134faa post.

The link says to install OpenGL SDK from Imagination Technology, link the library, and include the file to solve the error.

When I tried the mentioned steps, I got linker errors.

> link /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\4.7.4_2\lib" /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\4.7.4_2\lib" /NOLOGO /
>       NODEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES.LIB /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWSCE,6.00 /MACHINE:THUMB /DLL /
>       SAFESEH:NO /VERSION:4.74 /OUT:....\lib\QtGuid4.dll @C:\DOCUME~1\VARUN~1.JAJ\LOC
>       ALS~1\Temp\nm8796.tmp
>       Creating library ....\lib\QtGuid4.lib and object ....\lib\QtGuid4.exp
>       qegl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_eglBindAPI referenced
>        in function "public: bool __cdecl QEglContext::createContext(class QEglContext
>       *,class QEglProperties const *)" (?createContext@QEglContext@@QAA_NPAV1@PBVQEglP
>       roperties@@@Z)
>       ....\lib\QtGuid4.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>       NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\ce\bi
>       n\x86_arm\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
>       Stop.
>       NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\BIN\n
>       make.exe"' : return code '0x2'
>       Stop.
>       NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
>       Stop.

Has anyone faced similar problems?  Could you please suggest me what to do?